# How to update my existing serenity project to the latest available version

Tags: visual-studio, serenity-platform

Using visual studio 2019, how to check the version of my current serenity project? how can I update my existing serenity project to the latest available version.

Answer (score 1):

Use the nuget package manager given in VS